# GoogleSign In error in `swift 3`

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I feel funny to ask this question. I am using default `GoogleSign` in for my swift project.The changes in the values of height doesn't change the height of button.
Whether the value of height is 59 or 500, it displays fixed height.

//GoogleSignIn button

```
let signInButton = GIDSignInButton(frame: CGRect(x: 400, y: 144, width: 332,  height: 59))
```

Comment: yes it can not be change, you need to use `.style ` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give the custom size to your `GoogleSignIn` button. You can give only three types of size, using `style` property in button.

```
    signInButton.style = .IconOnly
    signInButton.style = .Standard
    signInButton.style = .Wide
```

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating Google Sing in button is not permitted. What you can instead do is either one of two. Display your own button on top of Google Sing in button or simply make your own costume button with it's own function.

Example

```
          //add google sing in button
    googleBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 116 + 66, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
    view.addSubview(googleBtn)

    let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    customButton.frame =  CGRect(x: 16, y: 116 + 66 + 66, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
    customButton.backgroundColor = .orange
    customButton.setTitle("Custom Google Sing in ", for: .normal)
    customButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    customButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlecustomgoogleSingin), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(customButton)
```

now the function

```
    func handlecustomgoogleSingin(){

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

    }
```

this should render something like this

[image]